# Moving some SharePoint administration outside of Central Administration?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, administration

Are there any out of the box or third-party tools for sharing some Central Admin-type administration tasks with site owners?

I have a client who has a SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Edition site where only two IT people have access to the Central Administration site. There are several sites with different site owners. My client would like to offer a subset of the administration features - primarily those centering around user management and auditing - to site owners, rather than having them relay their requests to the two IT guys (which is what they do now).

A concrete example: site owners would like to be able to create a new user account, as well as perform other user administration-related actions for users who can access their site (like resetting passwords). Similarly, they'd like to have access to audit reports to see what users accessed what documents, what documents were changed, and so on, as well as see reports on what users can access their site, their permission levels, etc. These reports can be viewed from the Central Administration website, but my client needs them accessible to the site owners, as well.

Any OOTB options here, or third-party tools that focus on these needs?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell from their marketing if it does exactly what you're asking for, but maybe enquire about the management and security options at http://share-gate.com

If trying to do this on the cheap, the free/paid editions of ADSelfService Plus from ManageEngine useful for user management. This is really a cheap/nasty solution which I wouldn't usually recommend; but you might be able to use PhantomJS to automate collection of those reports from CA, and upload them via WebDAV to the appropriate document library for the site owners.